# Custom Data Model for multiple Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 different models/tables that each can store custom fields. My 3 models are `Customer` `Product` and `Stock`.

Is there anyway to create a `CustomData` model mapped to a single table that can handle custom data for all 3 models? Currently I have a separate table/model for each model.

Customer Model:

```
[Table("Customer")]
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string CountryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CountryID")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Postcode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    //[RegularExpression(@"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\b")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Telephone")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomCustomerProperty> CustomProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Product Model:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductTypeID")]
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomProductData> CustomProperties { get; set; } 
}
```

Custom Product Model Property:

```
[Table("CustomProductData")]
public class CustomProductData
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomPropertyID { get; set; }

    public int CustomProductPropertyID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomProductPropertyID")]
    public virtual CustomProductProperty CustomProductPropertyType { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why you cant create the class whith contains your three models?

Comment: I'm not sure how the entity framework handles that

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can, however I think that the currently approach is better. Anyway, you should extend one of your classes to contain other properties (and maybe methods) - in this case, properties of your other classes.

To do this, create a partial class some where with the same name as one of those entity classes and the same assembly name.

Suppose that the EF generates the following entity class for you:

```
namespace myPrj
{
    public partial class Product
    {
        // auto generated class
    }
}
```

Now, you create a partial class like the following:

```
namespace myPrj
{
    public partial class Product
    {
        // your partial class.
        // Add properties of other entity classes here
        // and you'll have all of them within the Product entity class...
    }
}
```